# Make quartz only have one thread in clustered environment

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

I have a webapp with 2 instances and some cronjobs running from time to time. When only one scheduler Instance is running, the cronjobs are triggered after eachother  with the next waiting for the first one to be finished and that's exactly how I want it to function, because almost every cronjob is accessing the same data.

However if I start the scheduler in the second instance one the second cronjobs starts before the first has finished.

I found a few "solutions" and implemented tehm but they did not work.

my quartz.properties

```
# Use the MongoDB store
org.quartz.jobStore.class=com.novemberain.quartz.mongodb.MongoDBJobStore
# MongoDB URI (optional if 'org.quartz.jobStore.addresses' is set)
org.quartz.jobStore.mongoUri=
# comma separated list of mongodb hosts/replica set seeds (optional if 'org.quartz.jobStore.mongoUri' is set)
org.quartz.jobStore.addresses=mongodb://localhost:27017
# database name
org.quartz.jobStore.dbName=mytDb
# Will be used to create collections like mycol_jobs, mycol_triggers, mycol_calendars, mycol_locks
org.quartz.jobStore.collectionPrefix=quartz
# thread count setting is ignored by the MongoDB store but Quartz requries it
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=1
#set to true to enable the cluster funktions
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=true

org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval=20000

org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=AUTO
```

As you see I have a thread cont of 1 and what I think happens is that there are 2 Threads when there are two instances running.

So how can I configure quartz that there are two Scheduler instances running but only one is doing the work and the second to be used if one instance crashes.

I also added `@DisallowConcurrentExecution` on my Job classes but this seems not to work either.